# Library dependencies at run-time

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dependencies

In our project we have a dynamic library based on Qt which contains a lot of helper functions for different fields: sql, network, gui, xml processing etc. When building our lib it should be linked against several other standard libraries, such as QtCore, QtGui, QtSql etc.

I want to build a simple application that uses a couple of functions from our library. I build my app using MinGW on Windows.

I don't understand why my application at run-time needs all the libraries which our lib was linked against. I mean my app doesn't use any of sql stuff, but QtSql is still needed.

Let's assume I need to use only one function for xml processing. I want to have this configuration: my app + our lib + QtXml. Is it possible? I don't want to ship a number of libraries I don't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you link against QtSQL, the library will be loaded, regardless of whether you use it or not, because one of the functions inside your lib depends on it. If you only want to load some of the libraries, you can either split your own library or use `dlopen` and friends for the Qt libraries.

Comment: On Windows that would be `LoadLibrary` and friends `;-)`